# How to get the natural log of a big integer

Tags: go, biginteger, logarithm

I am trying to convert a string to integer and then to calculate its log.
My first approach was to convert the string using `strconv` library, but I got an error about the length of the string to be converted.

After that, I used `math/big` library which worked fine. Now I am not able to apply `math.Log()`on the resulted big integer.

Code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/big"
)

func main() {
    bb := "11948904162160164791281681976941230184120142151411311314211115130161285142991119211447"
    bi := big.NewInt(0)
    if _, ok := bi.SetString(bb, 10); ok {
        fmt.Println(math.Log(bi))
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("error parsing line %#v\n", bb)
    }

}
```

Error:

```
cannot use bi (type *big.Int) as type float64 in argument to math.Log
```

Comment: To what kind of precision? If around 15 digits is fine, just parse it as a float. If you need something comparable to the number of digits in the input, you're in for some work.

Comment: @hobbs the second option.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? This sounds like a problem that's expecting you to use the basic log identities, and not a library function.

Comment: In most situations, I don't see why you'd need a precision higher than the one offered by `float64`. But if you REALLY need it for some crazy reason, [this function](https://github.com/robpike/ivy/blob/master/value/log.go) by one of the golang devs might be useful.

Comment: @JimB not really, it's just some midnight crazy idea that hit my mind. I think I will go on now with the option with less precision.

Comment: Unfortunately Go's arbitrary-precision package provides no help on its own, *and* there's no usable interface to GMP or PARI (at least, that go-search can find). So doing the Maclaurin series yourself as Rob Pike did in the function @Gabriel linked seems to be the only answer apart from "use another language".

Answer (score 1):

There are very few situations in which you'd need a precision greater than the one provided by the standard `float64` type.

But just to satisfy any "midnight crazy ideas" (or even some very in-depth scientific research!) anyone might run into, Rob Pike's [implementations of some operations with big floats](https://github.com/robpike/ivy/tree/master/value) are probably the best you can get right now with Go. The `log` function can be found [here](https://github.com/robpike/ivy/blob/master/value/log.go).